# c# Error 1 The type or namespace name '' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a DLL of a base class that is inherited by classes in another DLL and I'm getting the above error when I name the namespace and the class anything but the default name.

This is what I want it to look like:

```
namespace SportsBaseClasses
{
   class BaseClass
   {
```

It works when it looks like this:

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
   public class Class1
   {
```

I'm using the appropriate "using" and I have it added as a reference. I've looked up this question half a dozen times and no one else seems to have this problem. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making `BaseClass` public.

```
namespace SportsBaseClasses
{
   public class BaseClass
   {
```

Comment: Thank you that is perfect i am so dumb i cant believe i missed that.

Answer (score 0):

Or may be try

```
using ClassLibrary1.Class1
```

OR

```
using BaseClass = ClassLibrary1.Class1
```